# python socket to read all receive packets

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to read all packets received on an interface.

```
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x0003))
        s.bind((interface,0))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print('Socket could not be created to read the traffic on %s. Error Code : %s ' %(interface, str(msg)))
        sys.exit()
    # receive a packet
    while True:
        packet = s.recvfrom(65565)

        print(packet)
```

It is able to read Arp, DHCP packet but NOT ICMP. Is it NOT "socket.ntohs(0x0003)" would include *all* packets? Please let me know if I'm missing something?

Comment: @TimRoberts then there's something really big I'm missing, because `man 3 ntohs` on my Mac doesn't talk about `ETH_P_ALL` either...

Comment: Yes, there is.  `ntohs` just prepares parameters for the `socket` call.  If you look up `socket`, you'll see that the third parameter is the `protocol` selector, and the value has to be converted into network byte order.  That's what `ntohs` does.

Comment: @TimRoberts OK, I see. Reading more on it now. Thanks!

Comment: To the OP, are you trying to capture ICMP messages to and from your interface, or are you trying to use promiscuous mode?  There are sometimes hardware-level optimizations for pings.

Comment: It started capturing the packets after I altered the destination MAC of ICMP packets destined to the interface MAC. So that concludes that we can only capture the packets destined to the interface and NOT the transit traffic. Anyone has any comments?